# Reat - Components/Containers: One view, multiple actions?

Tags: reactjs, components, containers

I'll try to be concise: I have a Filter View (Container) that combines dumb components like a Grid Component with results, and a Form Component with some fields and actions like submit. In this context that houses some doubts:
- In a case where I have a component (a dropdown for instance) that has its own data (a list of something), should it be responsible for fetching its own data or this should be delegate to its smart parent (Filter View)?
- This smart Filter View has many dumb components to take care, so, is it responsible for propagating all actions that those components need (for example: handleSearchClick, handleGridRowClick, etc.)?

If so, that should be the final structure:

- FilterView (smart)

  - Form (dumb, with callback actions received from FilterView)

    - TextField (dumb)
    - CustomerDropDown (smart? or should FilterView send data to it?)
  - Grid (dumb, with callback actions received from FilterView)

I hope I had explained well what I meant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluffy questions gets fluffy answers.

There is no real consensus on how to find the sweetspot for smart/dump components. There are a ton of blog posts about it and even the React docs are fuzzy about the concept. Assuming your using something like Redux, i would say, don't be afraid to connect your "deeper" components. Try and go for easier, cleaner code that makes sense to look at and reason about rather than to follow some exact science here.

At my current project, were we earlier followed the "pass all data from the top down", we have now switched to connecting lower components directly to the stores and actions that needs them. And that feels a lot better and works great for us. 
Our problem and why we switched are well described by others in the [Recommended usage of connect()](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/419) issue in the Redux repo.

With Redux and it´s connect component there are no real cost of connecting to the state more often so basically it´s all up to you, and your legacy.

Even if you're not using Redux i'm sure these blog posts and issues can help you.

Good read tips:
[Recommended usage of connect() #419](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/419)

[Abramov´s Smart and Dumb components blog post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Comment: Hi Per Svensson, thanks for rapid answer. That's my second project with React/Redux and my first serious one. One thing I didn't realize at the first glance (and I'd never do until I dig into the problem), is that using this Container/Component approach with deeper components is really tricky, and the chance of messing the whole thing is real. I'll take a look at the github issue you sent. I read Abramov's post about this but now I realized that I miss one important piece: "This is an ongoing process of refactoring so don’t try to get it right the first time.". Thanks again.

Comment: You can also see in the github issues that there has been a shift in library creators opinions. Earlier, right when redux came out, there was only the top down approach and it was even nailed on the React docs. Now neither Redux or the React teams (the same these days? ;) ) advocate one solution to rule them all. And regarding refactoring... oh yes, we refactor a lot as well.  :)